# ntfs-3g.usermap fails with "You have defined no user" on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, ntfs

The `ntfs-3g.usermap` command doesn't seem to work for me on an NTFS disk:

```
$ lsblk -no name,fstype | grep sdb1
└─sdb1                  ntfs
$ umount /dev/sdb1
$ mount | grep sdb1
$ sudo ntfs-3g.usermap /dev/sdb1

This tool will help you to build a mapping of Windows users
to Linux users.
Be prepared to give Linux user id (uid) and group id (gid)
for owners of files which will be selected.
"/dev/sdb1" opened

* Scanning "/dev/sdb1" (two levels)
* Search for "Documents and Settings" and "Users"
* Search for other directories /

   in directory "/"
   file "Autorun.inf" has no mapped group
By which Linux login should this file be owned ?
Enter gid of login, or just press "enter" if this file
does not belong to a user, or you do not known to whom

Group : 
"/dev/sdb1" closed

You have defined no user, no mapping can be built

$ ls UserMap*
ls: cannot access 'UserMap*': No such file or directory
```

The result is the same regardless if I just press `<Enter>` for the `Group :` prompt, or type some specific user name followed by `<Enter>`.

What can I do? I don't even know why it fails, can I find a more detailed error message somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I did write a dummy UserMapping file on the disk and re-mounted it, and this seems to have helped by enabling permissions on the drive. Still, that's more like a *workaround*; I'm still curious what's the proper *solution* to the original question.

What I did:

```
$ mkdir /media/akavel/Maxtor/.NTFS-3G
$ echo '::S-1-5-21-3333333333-222222222-111111111-10000' > /media/akavel/Maxtor/.NTFS-3G/UserMapping
$ umount /dev/sdb1
$ # click in File Explorer to mount automatically again
```